# eCognition+ R/Python workflow

Tags: python, r, ecognition

I am trying to generate a general classifier Model for basic LU classification using E-Cognition. Since my options for achieving so in the software are limited I thought of exporting the segmentation and sample statistics to R or Python and then performing the classification there. However, I still don't have a clear idea of how the workflow will be. Is there any available tutorial? Or can someone provide me with the basic workflow?

Comment: Here is some Python code I wrote in a Jupyter Notebook that highlights how to do image segmentation and classification: https://github.com/redfoxgis/image-segmentation-classification/blob/main/image_segmentation_classification.ipynb